# How to change the email that a drupal 8 contact form is sent to based on a parameter sent to the form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-contact-form

I have a content type in my Drupal 8 site called TeamMember which represents and employee at the company.  One of the fields is the employee's email address.  How can I link the email field to a contact form so that the proper employee receives the email?

Comment: How many employees does this company have? Could you make them be users, and utilize the per-user contact form?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the module, [Contact Emails](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_emails). Although I haven't used it, it seems to be made for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using rules module
Thanks

Comment: Could you point me to an example of this?  Somehow I'd like to be able to click on an email link from my teammember and have it go to a contact form and know that the email should go to the address on that teammember content.  But I can't find anything like that.  Any help would be appreciated.